# rxjs call function periodically or when timer expires

Tags: rxjs

I have a need to call a function every 5000ms after the function finishes.
how can i achieve this.

my current implementation just keeps calling every 5000ms even if function takes longer

```
const { BehaviorSubject, timer} = require("rxjs");


const subject = new BehaviorSubject(false)

async function doit() {
    console.log('hey')
    subject.next(true)
}

timer(0, 5000).subscribe(() => {
    doit()
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this was your intent but my solution starts counting the five second interval only after the function has finished. See the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/codepen0980/pen/VwWNNKO?editors=1012).

```
import { BehaviorSubject, of }  from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/rxjs@7.x?min';
import { exhaustMap, delay, repeat }  from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/rxjs@7.x/operators?min';

const subject = new BehaviorSubject(false)
const startTime = Date.now();
async function doit() {
    console.log('Time elapsed: '+(Date.now()-startTime));
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1200));
    subject.next(true)
}

of(undefined).pipe(
  exhaustMap(doit),
  delay(5000),
  repeat()
  ).subscribe();
```

The [following](https://codepen.io/codepen0980/pen/RwgOOJW?editors=0012) seems to work too:

```
import { BehaviorSubject, defer }  from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/rxjs@7.x?min';
import { delay, repeat }  from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/rxjs@7.x/operators?min';

const subject = new BehaviorSubject(false)
const startTime = Date.now();
async function doit() {
  console.log('Time elapsed: '+(Date.now()-startTime));
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1200));
  subject.next(true)
}

defer(doit).pipe(
  delay(1000),
  repeat()
).subscribe();
```

Comment: i guess i could change the behvioursubject to an number and return the time for function to complete.

then in subscribe set the delay to 5000 - duration


so delay was always 5000 no matter how long function takes

Answer (score 0):

Use exhaustMap, it will not take new item until it finishes doit. Make sure do it returns observable

```
timer(0, 5000).pipe(
   exhaustMap(_ => doit())
).subscribe();
```

Comment: Looks like exhaustMap works

```
    const { BehaviorSubject, exhaustMap, timer } = require("rxjs");
    const { promisify } = require('util');
    const sleep = promisify(setTimeout);

    async function doit() {
        const randomDuration = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000)
        console.log(new Date().toISOString(), `random duration ${randomDuration}`)
        await sleep(randomDuration)
    }

    timer(0, 5000).pipe(
        exhaustMap(_ => doit())
     ).subscribe();
```

Comment: Does this worked?

Comment: fighting the darn code block editor

Comment: 2021-10-02T20:56:38.300Z random duration 2701
2021-10-02T20:56:43.308Z random duration 6272
2021-10-02T20:56:53.314Z random duration 4823
2021-10-02T20:56:58.315Z random duration 6044
2021-10-02T20:57:08.323Z random duration 6030

Comment: Try using concatMap instead of exhaustMap

Comment: looks like exhaustMap does
every 5s if function timeout < 5s
or 5s after last function run

Comment: lemme think on what i need some more.

Comment: believe, like the first answer. 5s after doit completes